# Website down time and pooled connections were in use .net core MVC Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-mysql-database

While running a .net Core MVC application against Azure Mysql database, frequently we are getting the sites are running down / going offline issue.

After checking server error logs , we can see many instances of the following error close to website down time.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
> connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
> connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

This error is occured at line `connection.Open();`

Following is the code we used with all db related functions and all db calls are properly inside

```
using()
{
  
} // so we assume the connections should be closed without explicitly writing it 

    private MySqlConnection GetConnection { get { return new MySqlConnection(_ConnectionString); } }
     
    public void siteDbFunctions()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = GetConnection)
        {
            if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            string query = "...";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.CommandTimeout = 600;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", _EditorialCategoryID);
            command.Prepare();
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                  .....................;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Only work around at the moment is restart App Pool / Website . Is there a better approach to read / write from db to avoid this

Comment: What MySQL ADO.NET library and version are you using?

Comment: Do you have many long running queries? I see that the timeout is high.

Comment: Yes there are many long running queries and as it is a web app and site with many visitors, specially at times with more site visitors , any pages of the web app can be exposed  and multiple long running queries can be executed.  So which makes things bit more difficult

Comment: @BradleyGrainger "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="3.2.0" is currently used and it is a .net core 3.1 application . I have to try upgrading to latest version as well

Comment: Try setting Maximum Pool Size to a larger value. Default seems to be 100. Doc: https://mysqlconnector.net/connection-options/

Answer (score -2):

You used a new connection instance `return new MySqlConnection(_ConnectionString);`
"If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. " [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#remarks) You could try close the connection.
Maybe like following:

```
if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connection.Open();

    string query = "...";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    ......


    connection.Close();
}
```

Another thing I consider is even `connection` is disposed , but `GetConnection` is not in the "using" clause. You could try make it simply

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
```

Comment: I am just wondering what is the relevance of your first sentence. "_You used a new connection instance_". That is exactly what OP should do.

Comment: @Cleptus as he check if the connection is open, I think his purpose is to reuse connection. But he actually create a new instance every time.

Comment: I would suggest rewording trhe answer to something along the lines "using statement only disposes the unmanaged resources only if they are unused. You should close the connection".

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) says: "If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. **Close and Dispose** are **functionally equivalent**".

Comment: @Magnus that is `SqlConnection` which is SQL Server related. The question is about MySQL so your comment could be wrong.

Comment: @Cleptus `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` uses `MySqlConnector` and the `MySqlConnection` class can be found [here](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/blob/master/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlConnection.cs). As you see `Dispose` and `DisposeAsync` both call `CloseAsync`

Comment: "using statement only disposes the unmanaged resources only if they are unused. You should close the connection." This is factually incorrect and a misunderstanding of how `DbConnection.Dispose` works.